# Newly created TextInputs in FlatList lose focus after 10th row - initialNumToRender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm attempting to build a To-Do list feature for an application; however, I'm struggling to get it right.

Basically, I want a user to be able to create new list items via the "submit" key while typing, or a button (both already done). When the new list item is created, I want the corresponding TextInput within the FlatList to be automatically focused. This works...up to a certain point. Once I create 10 list items, the behavior stops working properly and the focus is no longer on the next, newly created FlatList item.

I've figured out that if I change the "initialNumToRender" property in the FlatList and increase it past 10, it will solve the problem, temporarily, until reaching that cap. However, I don't want to reduce the performance of my FlatList and I want to find a different solution. It seems to me that the entire FlatList is re-rendering past 10 items and the TextInput loses focus, but I haven't been able to grasp yet how to focus on the TextInputs created after the 10th row.

The FlatList in question:

```
      <FlatList
        key="flatlist"
        ListHeaderComponent={listHeader()}
        initialNumToRender={10}
        data={listItems}
        // TODO: Will need to change to use actual IDs at some point as opposed to just indexing
        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
          <>
            <View style={listStyles.itemView}>
              <Pressable onPress={() => radioButtonPressed(index)}>
                <MainListRadioButton completed={getRadioButtonState(index)} />
              </Pressable>
              {listItems[index].text.length > 0 ? (
                <TextInput
                  style={listStyles.itemText}
                  placeholder={`Item ${index + 1}`}
                  defaultValue={listItems[index].text}
                  value={listItems[index].text}
                  onChangeText={text => listItemTextChanged(text, index)}
                  ref={index === listItems.length - 1 ? lastListItemRef : null}
                  onSubmitEditing={() => addListItem()}
                />
              ) : (
                // Text input for "empty" list items so that a backspace can delete the entire row.
                <TextInput
                  style={listStyles.itemText}
                  placeholder={`Item ${index + 1}`}
                  defaultValue={listItems[index].text}
                  value={listItems[index].text}
                  onChangeText={text => listItemTextChanged(text, index)}
                  ref={index === listItems.length - 1 ? lastListItemRef : null}
                  onKeyPress={({nativeEvent}) => {
                    if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
                      deleteListItem(index);
                    }
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.divider} />
          </>
        )}
      />
```

How I'm implementing the behavior to shift focus to the next row so far:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastListItemRef.current) {
      lastListItemRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [listItems]);
```

Comment: Try wrapping your component in React.memo.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar, I tried this, unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Andrew, can you please provide a minimal working code? an expo snack will be great. ( on your provided coded, there are some code missing which make it challenging to debug )

Comment: I uploaded the majority of the code here: https://snack.expo.dev/R6Jmy58v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I actually ended up figuring it out myself. The steps I took were the following:

1. Completely remove setRef and ref within the TextInput and component.
2. Add autoFocus=true as a property to the TextInput. Previously I had a typo without capitalizing the F.
3. Change onTextChange to onEndEditing so the List Items only update after submitting text as opposed to on each text change.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using [scrollToIndex()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex) along with [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) since you're wanting to trigger the scroll on a visual change.

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex(listItems.length - 1)
}, [flatlistRef, listItems])
```

Comment: Not a scroll - I just want the text input row to be focused properly. Right now it defocuses, for some reasons after the 10th row.

Comment: you might use combination of scroll suggested here and focus after that scroll call

Answer (score 0):

Rather than controlling your `TextInput` focus at the parent level, you could turn your `listItem` function into a `ListItem` component. By doing this, you can store the ref to each new `ListItem` component within each component instance, and on mount of each component, focus it.

So your `DraggableFlatList` declaration becomes something like this:

```
<DraggableFlatList
  ...
  renderItem={({ item, index, drag, isActive }) => (
    <ListItem
      item={item}
      index={index}
      drag={drag}
      isActive={isActive}
      addListItem={addListItem}
      deleteListItem={deleteListItem}
      completed={getRadioButtonState(index)}
      text={listItems[index].text}
      onChange={listItemTextChanged}
      radioButtonPressed={radioButtonPressed}
    />
  )}
  ...
/>;
```

And your `ListItem` component definition looks something like this:

```
const ListItem = ({
  item,
  index,
  drag,
  isActive,
  text,
  completed,
  onChange,
  radioButtonPressed,
  addListItem,
  deleteListItem,
} = props) => {
  // Create ref to this TextInput
  const textRef = useRef(null);

  // On mount, set the TextInput focus
  useEffect(() => {
    if (textRef.current) {
      textRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Pressable style={listStyles.itemView} onLongPress={drag}>
        <Pressable onPress={() => radioButtonPressed(index)}>
          <MainListRadioButton completed={completed} />
        </Pressable>
        <TextInput
          ref={textRef}
          style={listStyles.itemText}
          placeholder={`Item ${index + 1}`}
          defaultValue={text}
          value={text}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChange(text, index)}
          onSubmitEditing={() => addListItem()}
          onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
            if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
              deleteListItem(index);
            }
          }}
        />
      </Pressable>
      <View style={listStyles.divider} />
    </>
  );
};
```

I've updated your snack here as a POC: https://snack.expo.dev/TZk_48CHF

Answer (score 0):

```
In this case you have to use the flatlist scrollToIndex function along with viewPosition property properly for the selected changes.Also you have to use the onScrollToIndexFailed prop in flatlist along with setTimeout.

viewPosition: 0.5 ---> put the selected item in middle,0 and 1 are other values

const const scrollToIndex = (ref, index = 0) => {
  if (ref && ref.current && index > -1) {
    ref.current.scrollToIndex({ index, viewPosition: 0.5 });
  }
};

const flatListRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex();
    setTimeout(() => {
      scrollToIndex(flatListRef, selectedIndex);
    }, 50);
  }, [title, flatListRef]);

<FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        initialNumToRender={categoryFilters.length + 1}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
          if (flatListRef !== null && info.index > -1) {
            setTimeout(
              () =>
                flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
                  index: info.index,
                  animated: true,
                  viewPosition: 0.5,
                }),
              50
            );
          }
        }}
        refreshing={false}
        data={listItems}
        listKey={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={()=>{}}
      />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, edit your formatting for people to understand the code/text part better

Answer (score 0):

you need to know if listItems is not a empthy array, for that reason you need to create this function isFechet() to evaluate it.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const goToFocus=await ()=>{
     if (lastListItemRef.current) {
      lastListItemRef.current.focus();
    }
   }
    
   if(isFechet(listItems)){
     goToFocus()
}
  }, [listItems]);
```